# "Merging" time ranges in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a bunch of time open/close "rules" that I wish to merge to get a consolidated set of rules for that day.

```
from datetime import time

times = [
    {"time_open": time(9, 0), "time_close": time(11, 0)},
    {"time_open": time(9, 0), "time_close": time(12, 0)},
    {"time_open": time(13, 0), "time_close": time(18, 0)},
    {"time_open": time(15, 0), "time_close": time(19, 0)},
]

# something would produce

merged_times = [
    {"time_open": time(9, 0), "time_close": time(12, 0)},
    {"time_open": time(13, 0), "time_close": time(19, 0)},
]
```

I have a few approaches in my head - but speed would probably be the primary driver for a chosen approach.

Comment: What is criteria of merging the rules ?

Comment: why the last item was removed from output?

Comment: Are your inputs sorted by opening and closing times?

Comment: @VanPeer: because the times overlap with the preceding opening times. Note that the times have been **merged**; the opening times of 13:00-18:00 and 15:00 - 19:00 have been combined into a single span of 13:00 -
 19:00

Comment: Related: [Merging Overlapping Intervals](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/69242), [Merging a list of time-range tuples that have overlapping time-ranges](//stackoverflow.com/q/5679638).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to start from a sorted set of intervals; if they are not yet sorted start with that:

```
from operator import itemgetter

sorted_times = sorted(times, key=itemgetter('time_open', 'time_close'))
```

You can then merge times simply by comparing start times to preceding end times; when they don't over lap yield the updated time:

```
def merge_times(times):
    times = iter(times)
    merged = next(times).copy()
    for entry in times:
        start, end = entry['time_open'], entry['time_close']
        if start <= merged['time_close']:
            # overlapping, merge
            merged['time_close'] = max(merged['time_close'], end)
        else:
            # distinct; yield merged and start a new copy
            yield merged
            merged = entry.copy()
    yield merged
```

This is a generator function, so merged times are yielded on demand. Use a loop to process these one by one, or use `list()` on the generator to pull all results into a list object.

Demo using your sample data (which happens to be sorted already):

```
>>> for entry in merge_times(times):
...     print(entry)
...
{'time_open': datetime.time(9, 0), 'time_close': datetime.time(12, 0)}
{'time_open': datetime.time(13, 0), 'time_close': datetime.time(19, 0)}
>>> list(merge_times(times))
[{'time_open': datetime.time(9, 0), 'time_close': datetime.time(12, 0)}, {'time_open': datetime.time(13, 0), 'time_close': datetime.time(19, 0)}]
```